# Why does the product of widths of two functions that are fourier transforms of each other have a lower limit?

Tags: fourier-transform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y282x.jpg)

Here f(x) and g(k) are fourier transforms of each other.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of just posting an image.

Comment: It is because of the convolution theorem. A strict width constraint can be interpreted as multiplication by a box which becomes convolution with a sinc function in the other domain. The width of the sinc is inversely proportional to the width of the box. Even if it is not a strict constraint but multiplication by a smoothly decaying function that never quite becomes 0 it often corresponds to convolution by a smoothly decaying function of inversely proportional width in the other domain. For example gaussians.